# Using certbot/lets-encrypt with DNS load balancing?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm creating multiple droplets for my website (scaled by load), so my DNS looks something like this:

```
www.somesite.com   A    1.2.3.4
www.somesite.com   A    6.7.8.9
```

Is it even possible to get a certificate for the same domain for more than one IP?

I'm using `certbot --apache --email=admin@domain -d www.domain` to install my certificates but it fails after the second droplet.

*P.S. I know DO offers a load-balancer but I can't use that for now*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have two servers behind the load balancer `a` and `b` and the servers terminate SSL.

Say the servers are running NGINX which supports proxying requests to another server (I suppose Apache can handle this too, but can’t confirm).

Say you don’t control DNS for the domains served by the servers (perhaps you are running a SaaS and allow users to use their own domain on your service).

Here are the steps we use at [Lickstats](https://lickstats.com/) to achieve this behind [DigitalOcean load balancers](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/load-balancer/).

**Step 1.** Install `certbot` on `a`.

**Step 2.** Configure NGINX on `b` to proxy Let’s Encrypt verification requests to `a`.

The following setup uses [Proxy Protocol](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy/proxy-protocol/) so we need to [bind NGINX to another port](https://serverfault.com/questions/978221/is-it-possible-to-enable-proxy-protocol-only-for-one-host-on-nginx) on `a`.

```sh
server {
    listen 80 proxy_protocol;
    listen 443 proxy_protocol ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ...

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        proxy_pass http://a.example.com:8080;
    }

    ...

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

**Step 3.** Get certificate using the [webroot](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot) plugin (this how-to might work using the apache plugin but I recommend using less automation for elaborate setups behind load balancers).

```sh
certbot -d example.com -d www.example.com --webroot --webroot-path /path/to/public/folder certonly
```

**Step 4.** Sync certs to `b` using `rsync` as root.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root"
    exit 1
fi

declare -a files=("/etc/letsencrypt/live" "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" "/etc/nginx/sites-available")
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    rsync -axLS --delete $file admin@b.example.com:sync
done

echo "Done"
```

**Step 5.** Apply certs on `b` using `rsync` as root.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root"
    exit 1
fi

data="/home/admin/sync"

if [ ! -d $data ]; then
    echo "$data folder not found"
    exit 1
fi

rsync -axS --delete $data/live/ /etc/letsencrypt/live
rsync -axS --delete $data/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
rsync -axS --delete $data/sites-available/ /etc/nginx/sites-available

chown -R root:root /etc/letsencrypt/live
chown -R root:root /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
chown -R root:root /etc/nginx/sites-available

if nginx-ensites.sh; then
    rm -r $data
    echo "Done"
fi
```

**Step 6.** Enable sites in `sites-available` by creating symbolic links to `sites-enabled`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root"
    exit 1
fi

nginx=/usr/sbin/nginx

rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*

files=( /etc/nginx/sites-available/* )
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    src=../sites-available/${file##*/}
    dest=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/${file##*/}
    if [ ! -f $dest ]; then
        ln -s $src $dest
    fi
done

if $nginx -t; then
    $nginx -s reload
    echo "All available sites have been enabled"
fi
```

**Step 7.** Use a cron job to attempt renewals once a month.

Comment: I guess there is no direct way to do it. I was afraid that the final solution might entail doing this sort of work and copying certs. Thanks for putting it all together and sharing the implementation!

Comment: That's a great answer !

Comment: Apache can't handle it. The way to do it like in nginx is Proxy balancer directives, but LE gives up too early as Apache has only lbmethods that fail with 404 to LE-end. And it gets worse with every blanacer group node added. It should have lbmethod keep-trying-all-nodes-until-succeed - but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The challenges `tls-sni-01` or `http-01` won't work because you cannot predict the server where the letsencrypt request will reach.

You can use the DNS challenge on a single server, and then rsync the resulting certificate on the other server.

Using certbot, you can use the command line `--preferred-challenges dns` and then add the TXT entry to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a certbot limitation. Presumably you have a way to deploy your site to those multiple IPs; now use the same way to deploy the challenge to those multiple IPs. Doesn't matter if it takes an hour, LE is patient. Whether certbot can aid you in this, I don't know, but there are plenty of other Let's Encrypt clients out there.

As the other answer said, dns-01 is easiest here, assuming you can automate DNS changes.